# Why I cant connect to instance of sqlserver?

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, sqlcmd

I have 3 instance of `sql server`:

```
MSSQLSERVER
SQLEXPRESS
SQLEXPRESS2008R2
```

I want to connect to `SQLEXPRESS2008R2` by this command:

```
sqlcmd -s .\SQLEXPRESS2008R2 -e
```

and than run this command:

```
use Dbs_TickSoft
go
```

but show me this error:

```
Database 'Dbs_TickSoft' does not exist...
```

If my database is connected:

[image]

Comment: Can't tell what is wrong at this point. Try run `sp_databases` after you are connected to list all databases on the server.

Comment: @isim show me 'master', 'model', 'msdb' and 'tempdb'

Comment: Those are your system databases. Are you sure you are connected to the right server where `Dbs_TickSoft` is created?

Comment: @isim yes, i am sure, The above picture is clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the `sqlcmd` [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx), there is a difference between the `-s` (lower case) and `-S` (upper case) arguments. The former specifies the column-separator character, while the latter specifies the SQL instance instance of to connect to. So changing your command to

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS2008R2 -e
```

with the upper case "S" should work.